# LEFT JOIN ON most recent date in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got two tables, both with timestamps and some more data:

## Table A

```
| name | timestamp           | a_data |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------ |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 11:10:00 | a      |
| 2    | 2018-01-01 12:20:00 | b      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:30:00 | c      |
```

## Table B

```
| name | timestamp           | b_data |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------ |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 11:00:00 | w      |
| 2    | 2018-01-01 12:00:00 | x      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | y      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:10:00 | y      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:10:00 | z      |
```

What I want to do is

1. For each row in **Table A** `LEFT JOIN` the most recent record in **Table B** that predates it.
2. When there is more than one possibility take the last one

## Target Result

```
| name | timestamp           | a_data | b_data |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------ | ------ |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 11:10:00 | a      | w      |
| 2    | 2018-01-01 12:20:00 | b      | x      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:30:00 | c      | z      | <-- note z, not y
```

I think this involves a subquery, but I cannot get this to work in Big Query. What I have so far:

```
SELECT a.a_data, b.b_data
FROM `table_a` AS  a  

LEFT JOIN `table_b` AS b 
ON a.name = b.name

WHERE a.timestamp = (
  SELECT max(timestamp) from `table_b` as sub
  WHERE sub.name = b.name
  AND sub.timestamp < a.timestamp
)
```

On my actual dataset, which is a very small test set (under 2Mb) the query runs but never completes. Any pointers much appreciated

Comment: In case of equality for case 3, which tells the "order" to take "last" one?

Comment: I just want the last one entered into the table, ideally. Unfortunately there is no column to use for this selection - doesn't need to be highly reliable, as there are very few cases where this duplication occurs, so would settle for randomly selecting one of the other.

Comment: in DB engines there is no last entered, you need to have a field, otherwise it will be picked one randomly, think that this runs in a distributed environment, you need to supply an order field.

Comment: Random is probably okay for this problem, there are only duplicates in very rare cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use a select subquery.

```
SELECT a.*,(
    SELECT MAX(b.b_data) 
    FROM `table_b` AS b 
    WHERE 
        a.name = b.name 
    and  
        b.timestamp < a.timestamp
) b_data 
FROM `table_a` AS  a
```

**EDIT**

Or you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function in a subquery.

```
SELECT name,timestamp,a_data , b_data
FROM (
    SELECT a.*,b.b_data,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.name ORDER BY b.timestamp desc,b.name desc) rn 
    FROM `table_a` AS  a  
    LEFT JOIN `table_b` AS b ON a.name = b.name AND b.timestamp < a.timestamp
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to do with a left join without specifying all the columns? In reality, there are a lot more columns than b_data. Thanks

Comment: @wab Could you provide more sample data and expect the result for your situation?

Answer (score 2):

In BigQuery, arrays are often an efficient way to solve such problems:

```
SELECT a.a_data, b.b_data
FROM `table_a` a LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.name,
             ARRAY_AGG(b.b_data ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(1)] as b_data
      FROM `table_b` b 
      GROUP BY b.name
     ) b
     ON a.name = b.name;
```

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff - that works, but how would I bring other columns along with the join? In the above example I've just got `b_data`, but in the actual data set I want to join on multiple columns based on the rule you've coded above.

Comment: @wab . . . Then you would use D-Shih's answer with `row_number()`.  This question is specifically about one column, which is why I provided this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and does not require specifying all columns on both sides - only `name` and `timestamp`. So it will work for any number of the columns in both tables (assuming no ambiguity in name rather than for above mentioned two columns)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a.*, b.* EXCEPT (name, timestamp)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    ANY_VALUE(a) a, 
    ARRAY_AGG(b ORDER BY b.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] b
  FROM `project.dataset.table_a` a
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table_b` b
  USING (name)
  WHERE a.timestamp > b.timestamp
  GROUP BY TO_JSON_STRING(a)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a common case where you can't just `Group by` and get the minimum. I suggest the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a as a inner join (SELECT name, min(timestamp) as timestamp
                              FROM table_b group by 1) as b 
on (a.timestamp = b.timestamp and a.name = b.name)
```

This way you limit it only to the minimum present in Table b, as you specified.

You can also achieve that in a more readable way using the `WITH` statement:

```
WITH min_b as (
SELECT name, 
min(timestamp) as timestamp
FROM table_b group by 1
)
SELECT *
FROM table_a as a inner join min_b 
on (a.timestamp = min_b.timestamp and a.name = min_b.name)
```

Let me know if it worked!