# LEFT JOIN ON most recent date or dates in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

My problem is similar to [LEFT JOIN ON most recent date in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53726282/left-join-on-most-recent-date-in-google-bigquery)
However, I would like to join on possible 1 (or more) recent days, if there are more than 1 with the same name in table A.

`TABLE A`

```
| name | timestamp           | a_data |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------ |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 11:10:00 | a      |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 11:10:00 | h      |
| 2    | 2018-01-01 12:20:00 | b      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:30:00 | c      |
```

`TABLE B`

```
| name | timestamp           | b_data |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------ |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 11:00:00 | w      |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 10:30:00 | i      |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 | j      |
| 2    | 2018-01-01 12:00:00 | x      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | y      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:10:00 | y      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:10:00 | z      |
```

What I want to do is

1. For each row in Table A `SQL LEFT JOIN` the most recent record in Table B that predates it.
2. When there is more than one possibility take the last one.
3. When there is more than one of same name in Table A, then don't take the last one, but the second last one. And so on.

Basically this means I want to pair each row in Table A with the latest (if not already taken) row in Table B if possible, otherwise just drop the row.

Target Result

```
| name | timestamp           | a_data | b_data |
| ---- | ------------------- | ------ | ------ |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 11:10:00 | a      | w      |
| 1    | 2018-01-01 11:10:00 | h      | i      | <-- note h, i
| 2    | 2018-01-01 12:20:00 | b      | x      |
| 3    | 2018-01-01 13:30:00 | c      | z      | <-- note z, not y
```

Also, there are actually 3 columns (including name) that is the identifier for each row in each table.

Is a iteration needed or can I do it some other way? I tried all the answers in the previous question but I did not get it to work. Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT name, 
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a_ts AS `timestamp`, a_data) ORDER BY a_ts DESC, a_data)[SAFE_OFFSET(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY b_ts DESC, b_data DESC) - 1)].*, 
    b_data 
  FROM (
    SELECT name, b_data, b.timestamp AS b_ts, a.timestamp AS a_ts, a_data
    FROM `project.dataset.tableB` b
    LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.tableA` a
    USING(name)
  )
  WHERE b_ts <= a_ts
  GROUP BY name, b_data, b_ts
)
WHERE NOT `timestamp` IS NULL
```

If to apply to sample data from  your question - result is

```
Row name    timestamp           a_data  b_data   
1   1       2018-01-01 11:10:00 a       w    
2   1       2018-01-01 11:10:00 h       i    
3   2       2018-01-01 12:20:00 b       x    
4   3       2018-01-01 13:30:00 c       z
```

Please note: in TableA there is no way to identify which is first and second to process between `a` and `h`. Same for `y` and `z` in TableB. To make this distinction - you need to have/add some extra rule that will define the order of those above mentioned. For simplicity sake (and any way this is the only available to use having your sample) I am using alphabetical order of respective `a_data` and `b_data` fields